# Unable to find the FromAddress of a send job using FuelSDK in Python

Tags: fuel-sdk, python

I am trying to find the FromAddress associated with particular send jobs using the FuelSDK package in Python.  After scouring through the documentation and source code, it doesn't appear to be anywhere.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Edit: Here's the sample piece of code I'm running, which is resulting in an empty response.results list:

import FuelSDK

clientid = "CLIENT ID GOES HERE"

clientsecret = "CLIENT SECRET GOES HERE"

stubObj = FuelSDK.ET_Client(params={'clientid':clientid,'clientsecret':clientsecret})

et_send = FuelSDK.ET_Send()

et_send.auth_stub = stubObj

response = et_send.get()

print(response.results[0]['FromAddress'])

Comment: Hey bro! Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I see FromAddress coming through in the following code:

```
import FuelSDK
import config # I defined my ET connection credentials in a separate module

myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(params=config.settings_production)

et_send = FuelSDK.ET_Send()
et_send.auth_stub = myClient

et_send.search_filter = {'Property': 'ID', 'SimpleOperator': 'equals', 'Value': YOUR_SEND_ID}
response = et_send.get()

print(response.results[0]['FromAddress'])
```

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't working for me.  What version of FuelSDK are you using?  Mine doesn't have an ET_Send method (version 0.9.3)  And I just downloaded config (version 0.3.9), but that doesn't have a settings_production method either.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using my fork of 1.0.0. https://github.com/nxorable/FuelSDK-Python/tree/v1.0.0
Sorry for the confusion: config is a local module I used to store my ET connection credentials.

Comment: I tried running this, but response.results comes out as an empty list.  I'm not getting any actual error messages, just an empty results list.  Do you have any insight into why this is happening?  I've tried with and without a search_filter.

Comment: What about these other response properties: status, code, message?

Comment: I get the following for those: status = True ; code = 200 ; message = 'OK'

Comment: It sounds like you just don't have any Sends for that account; hence, you're getting an empty list

Comment: But when I run other methods in FuelSDK--ET_SentEvent(), ET_ClickEvent() etc. I'm getting back results, and my results have values for the SendID field.  Do you know why I would be getting back results in those cases, but I'm not in this case?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to edit your question and post a simple version of your code that attempts to retrieve a Send

Comment: I get an empty list if I try to look up a Send ID for an ID that does not exist.

Comment: I added my code to my question above.  Even without a filter, I'm still getting an empty list as a result.